# Reinstalled app keeps previous coredata with cloudkit

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I am using iCloudKit with CoreData to sync and recover data. I want to sync data manually. I have data saved in CoreData and I have not synched data with CloudKit. If I reinstall the app, then it still shows the previous record.

Comment: When the app is deleted, the data associated with it also deletes. There is no way your data is persisted after you uninstall the app unless you are fetching it from any external source like firebase and CloudKit. Check your code thoroughly.

Comment: there is no data in sqlite file but after sometime when Cloudkit finishes its task in background then it adds data in sqlite file. The log  contains this:
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitImporterZoneChangedWorkItem applyAccumulatedChanges:error:]_block_invoke_2(400): <PFCloudKitImporterZoneChangedWorkItem: 0x6000006b1050> {
(
    "<CKRecordZoneID: 0x6000034e2260; ownerName=__defaultOwner__, zoneName=com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone>"
)
} - Importing updated records:
(

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. When I created project I had selected CloudKit. So by default it had used NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. So these container was causing the problem.

Comment: I am experiencing some issue you were experiencing. I have an app that uses CoreData + Cloudkit to save data and sync across devices. The issue is when the app is deleted the app does not show the data that was previously there before but an empty view. This means it does not get the data from CloudKit. I will appreciate your feedback.